# Find column locations of vector elements inside a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indices

Given a vector such as `a = [2 5 9]` and a matrix such as

```
    8  11  5 
b = 2   6  1
    4   9  3
```

What's the best way to find which column of `b` contains each element of `a`? In this example I'd want an output like `[1 3 2]` because `2` is in the first column, `5` is in the third column, and `9` is in the second column. For my purposes it's safe to assume that a number can only appear in one column.

Comment: What output do you expect for `b=magic(4)` and `a=[5,6,2,1]`? rayryeng and Divakar both implemented something different, which by chance returns the same for your example.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'd expect `1,3,2,4` for the example you posted. Thanks for noticing that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach -

```
[colID,~] = find(squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,b,permute(a,[1 3 2])),1)))
```

Or if you would like to avoid `squeeze` and `any` -

```
[~,colID,~] = ind2sub([size(b) numel(a)],find(bsxfun(@eq,b(:),a)))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this, why is the desired output vector an argument to the `permute` function?

Comment: @siegel haha I am not inputing the input into it. `[1 3 2]` are the dimensions that I am shiftiing with `permute`. So, with it, I am telling it to exchange dim-2 and dim-3, keeping dim-1 as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use `ismember`:

```
A = [2 5 9];
B = [8 11 5; 2 6 1; 4 9 3];
[~, ind] = ismember(A,B);
[~, col] = ind2sub(size(B), ind)

col = 

1   3   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
[~, index] = ismember(a, b);
[row, col] = ind2sub(size(b, 1), index);
```